# prevent a program from busy mode while working

Tags: c#, multithreading

i am making a program which sends many emails at a time and i noticed while the program is working it goes on busy mode i.e : i can not edit anything or touch anything and i made a function to show the number of successfully sent emails and the failed ones on a label so that the user can monitor the sent emails , now i got a problem the label shows the integer number after the program has done sending emails , i want to prevent that , i tried using the threading mode but failed it . and here is the code :

int success = 0;

```
    private void success()
    {
        label17.Text = success.ToString();
    }

    private void sendmail()
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(comboBox1.Text);
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(textBox6.Text, textBox7.Text);
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress(textBox3.Text, textBox1.Text);
        message.Subject = textBox4.Text;
        message.Body = richTextBox1.Text;
        if (textBox5.Text != "")
        {
            message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(textBox5.Text));
        }

        string bulkpath = textBox2.Text;

        foreach(string eachmail in File.ReadAllLines(bulkpath))
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(success);          // Kick off a new thread
            t.Start();  

            message.To.Add(eachmail);
            try
            {
                client.Send(message);
                success++;
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("One has not passed :(");
            }
            message.To.Clear();
        }

    }
```

Comment: You should be doing the *sending* in a background thread, and the UI updating in the UI thread. I don't have time to write any more right now, but that's the basis of it. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/threads/winforms.shtml

Answer (score 2):

Use [BackgroudWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to start a new thread and put your `sendmail()` completely in another thread. After use [ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx) method to notify to Main thread about percentage completed, in your case about quantity of mails sent.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Optionally you can simply start a new Thread which is responsible for sending the mail

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(sendMail));
t.Start();
```

When using the BackgroundWorker you're able to implement progress notifications and you're able to receive a callback when your action has finished in the background.

Thorsten

Answer (score 0):

Those solutions provided by other guys are perfectly valid, but needs some control over `Thread` and `BackgroundWorker` i recommend you to use Asynchronous send method.

Try this :

```
    void Send()
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(client_SendCompleted);
        client.SendAsync(/* METHOD's PARAMS */);
    }

    void client_SendCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null || e.Cancelled)
        {
            // TODO : Report error
        }
    }
```

hope this help.