# How can I use backgroundworker in my browser?

Tags: c#, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I'm trying to create my own web browser for my practice on windows application. So I've make a windows form for web browser. Now I want to use `backgroundworker` or `progressbar` to show real process of page loading but I don't know how to do it. I tried with Google but no result for me. So please help me if my question is right to ask about it.

Comment: You can see responces in my post on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882037/prevent-a-program-from-busy-mode-while-working/6882051#6882051

Comment: You can see my responce on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882037/prevent-a-program-from-busy-mode-while-working/6882051#6882051

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        // add progress bar
        private ProgressBar progressBar1;


        //create event for ProgressChanged 
        Browser.ProgressChanged += Browser_ProgressChanged;
        ...

        // set progress bar value when ProgressChanged event firing 
        void Browser_ProgressChanged(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
        if (e.MaximumProgress > 0) {
            int prog = (int)(100 * e.CurrentProgress / e.MaximumProgress);
            progressBar1.Value = prog;
        }
    }
```

- [C# Winforms: Using a progress bar with Web Browser Control](http://hashfactor.wordpress.com/2009/03/31/c-winforms-using-a-progress-bar-with-web-browser-control/)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/bgworkercomponent.aspx